# Set background color of "entire row" of nested li element on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a nested dropdown menu of ul/li elements, and when i hover a sub menu element, i want to have the background color stretch outside the boundaries of the inner li-element (as wide or wider than the parent element) making it seem as an "entire row" is selected.

I am using bootstrap and some customisation. I have included parts of the relevant CSS below (not all formatting included - can supply more if needed), but I suppose you get the gist of it.

[This is how the menu item looks now when hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUGkQ.png)

[This is how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSwqM.png)

Is this possible to achieve in an easy way?

HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="container header">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default header-holder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a accesskey="2" href="#">Kvoter og Fangst</a>
                    <div class="drop-holder">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled drop">
                            <li>
                                Fangst
                                <ul class="list-unstyled drop2">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Innmeldingsjournal</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Dagens auksjoner</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Valuta</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Kart</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Kvote
                                <ul class="list-unstyled drop2">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Kvotestatistikk</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Fart&#248;ykvoter</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Statistikk
                                <ul class="list-unstyled drop2">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Kvote</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Omsetning</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Partial snippet of relevant CSS code:

```
li {
     list-style: none;
}

.header-holder {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
}

.header-holder .nav li {
    text-align: left;
}

.header-holder .nav li.hover .drop-holder, .header-holder .nav li:hover .drop-holder {
    max-height: 9999px;
}

.header-holder .nav li.hover .drop-holder .drop, .header-holder .nav li:hover .drop-holder .drop {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.header-holder .nav li.hover > a, .header-holder .nav li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0559a2;
}

.header-holder .nav .drop li a:hover {
    background: none;
}

.header-holder .nav .drop .drop2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px 10px 9px;
}

.header-holder .nav .drop .drop2 li {
    margin: 0 0 5px 1px;
}

.header-holder .nav .drop .drop2 li a {
    padding: 0;
    color: #0559a2;
    background: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}

.header-holder .nav .drop .drop2 li a:focus, .header-holder .nav .drop .drop2 li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #434343;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.header-holder .nav .drop .drop2 li:hover {
    background-color: #edf3f8;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.header-holder .drop-holder {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all .25s linear;
}
```

Comment: where is header-holder at? the css doesn't help cause you're missing that class

Comment: provide full code

Comment: Can you provide the css children li  of ".drop" class.

Comment: My bad .. Forgot to add HTML nodes to the root.. Updated, and have included more CSS with some alterations to better illustrate the issue..

There is no css for children li of drop class besides a:hover..

Answer (score 1):

see snippet below.

changed the colors a bit for example purposes only

do not use `padding` on the `ul.drop2` but instead indent the `li` by adding padding to it. so it will have the width of the entire `ul.drop2`

let me know if this is what you are looking for

```css
 .drop-holder {
        width: 250px;
    }           

     .nav .drop .drop2 li a {
        padding: 0;
        color: #0559a2;
        background: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: block;
    }

   .nav .drop .drop2 li:hover {
        background-color: blue;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
     .nav li { list-style:none}
       .nav ,  .nav  ul { padding:0;}
.nav  ul.drop2 li { padding:0 10px; }      
.drop-holder { border:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li>
    <a accesskey="2" href="#">Kvoter og Fangst</a>
    <div class="drop-holder">
        <ul class="list-unstyled drop">
            <li>
                Fangst
                <ul class="list-unstyled drop2">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Innmeldingsjournal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dagens auksjoner</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Valuta</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Kart</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Kvote
                <ul class="list-unstyled drop2">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Kvotestatistikk</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Fart&#248;ykvoter</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Statistikk
                <ul class="list-unstyled drop2">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Kvote</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Omsetning</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove width of .drop-holder {width: 250px;}

Comment: yes. it will expand on the whole width. it depends on the width of the container that holds all the nav. ( the leftcol in your picture )

Answer (score 1):

You can't access any parent element via CSS, but you can fake it by using :before or :after to extend beyond the selected element itself. Alternatively, you could make the child stretch by changing it's padding on hover - code pasted below.

```css
.header-holder .nav .drop .drop2 li:hover {
  background-color: #edf3f8;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding-left: 100%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  padding-right: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use below mentioned `CSS`

Remove `width`

```
.drop-holder {
        width: 250px;
    }
```

Add below mentioned CSS

```
.drop > li{
padding:0 30px;
}
.drop ul{
margin:0 -30px;
}
.drop ul li{
padding:0 40px;
}
```